# AbstractMavenReport environmant variables Jobname and Jenkins_home

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

How can I get the **Jobname** and the **Jenkins_home** Path in an AbstractMavenReport? 
I have extendet the AbstractMavenReport in my own ReportingClass. There I whant to get the Jobname or the JobFolder where this Reporting Class is executed. Not the WorkinspaceFolder!

I've tried to set it with Parameter expressions like:

```
   /**
     * @parameter expression="${JOB_NAME}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    private File jobname;
```

or

```
    /**
     * @parameter expression="${env.JOB_NAME}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    private File jobname;
```

But I had no success.

Comment: You shouldn't define that in the expression you should define that in your pom file later. Apart from that you are using old style XDoclet instead of annotation based implementation...and why are you implementing a report plugin ? For what purpose?

Comment: In our Project we want to have a report that upgrades a html keeping the statistic of different testruns. therefore we need the JobFolder to parse different reportfiles. Ok maybe I can define an property in the pom and request that in the report by a parameter.